# Is the Inner Product a uniformly continuous function?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

I know it's continuous but is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: Please clarify. What is your vector space here? Do you mean continuous in one variable or in both simultaneously?

Comment: I would like to know in any given space. But let's assume the we are working on a Hilbert space. In both variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if $X$ is non-trivial.

Consider any $x \in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$.  We note that for any $\delta > 0$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$
\langle x + \delta x,nx\rangle = \langle x,nx\rangle + n\delta \langle x,x\rangle = \langle x,nx\rangle + n\delta 
$$
so that
$$
|\langle x + \delta x,nx\rangle - \langle x,nx\rangle| = n \delta
$$
the conclusion follows.

---

I think the function $\sqrt{\langle x,y \rangle}$ will be uniformly continuous on both variables, though.